# Context 0x3c74b38 is disconnected. No proxy will be used to service the request on the COM component.

Tags: c#, sharpdevelop

I am developing a window application in Microsoft visual C # 2008 express edition.I get a run time error wen i run the application.

```
string[] diskArray;
string driveNumber;
string driveLetter;

**searcher1 = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition");**
foreach (ManagementObject dm in searcher1.Get()) 
{
    diskArray = null;
    driveLetter = getValueInQuotes(dm["Dependent"].ToString());
    diskArray = getValueInQuotes(dm["Antecedent"].ToString()).Split(',');
    driveNumber = diskArray[0].Remove(0, 6).Trim();
    if(driveLetter==this._driveLetter)
    {
        /* This is where we get the drive serial */
        ManagementObjectSearcher disks = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");

        foreach (ManagementObject disk in disks.Get()) 
        {
            if (disk["Name"].ToString() == ("\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE" + driveNumber) & disk["InterfaceType"].ToString() == "USB") {
                this._serialNumber = parseSerialFromDeviceID(disk["PNPDeviceID"].ToString());
```

(in the highlighted line)

Context 0x3c74b38 is disconnected.  No proxy will be used to service the request on the COM component. This may cause corruption or data loss. To avoid this problem, please ensure that all contexts/apartments stay alive until the application is completely done with the RuntimeCallableWrappers that represent COM components that live inside them.

Answer (score 0):

Likely, you can find in the inner exceptions another one, e.g.

```
COMException: The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread.
```

That means you have to call your methods in another thread. Likely if you review the call stack you'll find an event handler what calls this code. Just use [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)/[BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) method to call your code. See example below:

```
if (this.InvokeRequired) // in some cases this condition will not work
{
    this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() { this.Your_Method(); }));
    return;
}
```

I got similar error when a USB device has been disconnected. But in my case I got it in autogenerated WMI wrap class which I called in LibUsbDotNet event handler.